# Chat list system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, chat

recently i was trying to build a conversation list, whereby a list of conversations will be displayed on the left and users can click which one they want to see, therefore, i wrote the following:

aJax:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            (document).on("click", "#leftconversation", function(){
    var cid = $(this).attr('class'); //you are getting the user id here
     var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "conversation.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: { cid: cid },
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            self.html("Loading please wait...");
                        }
                    });

    //WHEN SUCCESS
    request.success(function( data ) {

        $("#right").html(data); //this line will replace the right with echoed content from php file
    });

});
</script>
```

Basically this code here waits for users to select the div (id left conversation) and when users select, gets the class of the div which is assigned an unique variable for varied conversations, after which POSTING the cid to the conversation.php page which processes the data in database, and echoes out the html, with which ajax appends to div id right.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
            session_start();
            include_once("config.php");
            if (isset($_POST['cid'])){
            $query= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT R.cr_id,R.time,R.reply,U.Memberid,U.Username,U.Email, U.Picture FROM members U, conversation_reply R WHERE R.user_id_fk=U.Memberid and R.c_id_fk='".$_POST['cid']."' ORDER BY R.cr_id ASC LIMIT 20") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
            $cr_id=$row['cr_id'];
            $time=$row['time'];
            $reply=$row['reply'];
            $user_id=$row['Memberid'];
            $username=$row['Username'];
            $email=$row['Email'];
            $picture=$row['Picture'];
            echo '<div class=commments>';
            echo '<div id=left2>';
            echo '<img height="70px" width="55px" src="profileimage/'.$picture.'">';
            //echo $username;
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id=right2>';
            echo $reply;
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div> <div style="clear:both"></div>';


            }}else {
            echo 'Sorry it failed'; 


            }

            ?>
```

This code down here fetches all the conversation replies and echoes it out back to ajax for ajax to print it out, however, this script does not work and clicking on the div does not even do anything. I didn't set a datatype, so I'm not sure whether that could be causing the error, but i don't think so. Is there any step which i did wrongly?

Thanks!

Comment: "this script does not work" is not a very helpful description of your problem. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: First determine whether it's the ajax or the php that holds the problem

Comment: In your example, you have `(document).on`.  It's missing the `$`, it should be `$(document).on`.  Is that in your actual code?

Comment: hi there, yeah i have it inside, how do i print ajax errors? PHP is not giving me any errors and i doubly checked my database values/connection and everything is correct. I highly suspect its the ajax not working, how do you print the errors out? thanks!

Comment: i checked my console and it seems to tell me function statements must have a name